# List values from one column not found in the other

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

This is the table:

```
NotAvailable    Available   AllClasses  column4(Requird)
class1          class4      class1      class4
class2          class5      class2      class5
class3          class6      class3      class6
                class4      class7
                class5      class8
                class6      class9
                class7  
                class8  
                class9  
                class10
```

The logic is: check if any values from the **column C** (AllClasses) **is not** in in the first **column A** (NotAvailable), then copy that value to **column D**. Thus making a list of items from **column C** not found in **column A**.

The goal is to create a list of those items, and I suppose using **index match** formula.

Comment: put this question in http://superuser.com/ website and i will write a working answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, the formula below will check the value from ColC (AllClasses) and see if it is found in ColA (NotAvailable) and if not, copy it to ColD (Column4) in the same row.  You could sort ColD after to remove blanks.

Assumptions:

- Data is in the columns described above.

  =IF( ISERROR( VLOOKUP( $C2, $A$2:$A$10, 1, FALSE)), $C2, "")

Comment: Thanks! work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
=FILTER(AllClasses,REGEXMATCH(AllClasses,JOIN("|",NotAvailable))=false)
```

to make formula work, paste this in cell D2:

```
=FILTER(OFFSET(C2,,,COUNTA(C2:C)),
REGEXMATCH(OFFSET(C2,,,COUNTA(C2:C)),JOIN("|",OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))))=false)
```